# how to avoid back button issues with modal using :focus attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a modal technique which uses the fact that you can use different css rules when focused:

```
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in; 
    pointer-events: none;

}
#overlay:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

where #overlay is a div. I focus the overlay by having a link on my page with an event listener that does the following:

```
location.hash = '#overlay';
```

thus putting the overlay into focus and making the opacity 1.

The problem is that then when I close the modal and then click on the browser's back button, it brings me back to my_url#overlay .

Is there a way to avoid this while still using the location.hash technique for opening a modal?

Comment: "The problem is that then when I close the modal and then click on the browser's back button, it brings me back to my_url#overlay" - that shouldn't happen. It should just take you back to "my_url". Can you explain why if you hit "back" the URL still has "#overlay"?

Comment: it doesn't still have overlay. When I close the modal, then the url becomes "my_url". Then I click back and I get "my_url#overlay"

Comment: "*When I close the modal, then the url becomes "my_url"*" - how does that happen?

Comment: @MichaelCoker Sorry for being unclear: it becomes "my_url#" because I have a link with href="#" to close the modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a click handler on your "close" link that calls `history.back();` instead of following the `#` link.

```
// show overlay
document.getElementById('showOverlay').addEventListener('click',function(e) {
  location.hash = '#overlay';
  e.preventDefault();
});
// hide overlay
document.getElementById('closeOverlay').addEventListener('click',function(e) {
  history.back();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This also works, like @bowheart's solution, although I think I will just use a class instead of a :target rule to avoid refreshing the page.

Comment: @user3494047 np. This causes a page refresh for you? It shouldn't.

Comment: Hm, I see. It doesn't. I tested it in my console of the browser (just running history.back() ) and it refreshed, so I assumed that it would when there is a #  in the url as well. I see that it doesn't. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you close the modal, you are clearly doing some sort of routing. So, instead of whatever you're doing, you can use `window.location.replace()` to remove the current item in the history stack (the one containing `#overlay`), replacing it with a new one.

So if all you need is to remove the anchor from the url on modal close, you should be able to do:

```
location.replace(location.href.replace('#overlay', ''));
```

and the url containing the anchor will be gone from the browser history.

Comment: Thanks. This does work, although it causes a refresh which is a bit annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, if you're using Javascript to set the hash already, why bother with CSS `:target` instead of a class when `#overlay` is visible?

eg.

```
#overlay.show { … }
```

If you're going for something that works with or without Javascript—which is commendable but tricky—then you need to use the latter to both set a class and prevent the `<a href="#overlay">` click from reaching the address bar.

---

As an aside, if you're using `opacity` alone to affect the visibility of `#overlay` then I want to warn you that while invisible it will still take mouse inputs. This would also prevent inputs from reaching elements underneath the invisible `#overlay`.